# Какие минимальные компоненты нужно установить чтобы использовать Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Какие минимальные компоненты нужно установить чтобы использовать Xamarin?

Полностью они будут скачивать 26 Гб. Но у меня медленный Интернет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из-за медленного интернета прерывается с ошибкой установка Xamarin. После попыток запустить занова происходят новые ошибки. VS после этого не запускается, приходится восстанавливать точку восстановления  системы до установки.

```
Download of 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/10676430/d68d54e233c956ff79799fdf63753c54/Xamarin.Forms.Templates.vsix' succeeded using engine 'Bits'
Error: Package 'Xamarin.Apple.Sdk,version=10.10.0.37' failed to download from 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/10675927/d68d54e233c956ff79799fdf63753c54/Xamarin.Apple.Sdk.vsix'. WebClient download failed: Размер скачанного файла не соответствует размеру содержимого.. Bits download failed: Файл не найден.. WinInet download failed: Function: InternetReadFile, HR: -2147012894, Message: Unknown error 12002, Signature: PackageId=Xamarin.Apple.Sdk;PackageAction=DownloadPackage;ReturnCode=0x80131500
microsoft.visualstudio.telemetry.dll
microsoft.visualstudio.telemetry.dll
microsoft.visualstudio.telemetry.dll
microsoft.visualstudio.telemetry.dll
microsoft.visualstudio.telemetry.dll
microsoft.visualstudio.setup.dll
Skipping download of package 'Xamarin.VisualStudio,version=4.5.0.486' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.




Не удалось скачать пакет "Xamarin.Android.Sdk,version=7.1.0.41" из "https://download.microsoft.com/download/0/E/C/0ECDDDAB-5EB9-4163-BBB1-CF4CC906003D/Xamarin.Android.Sdk.vsix".
    URL-адрес поиска: https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Xamarin.Android.Sdk;PackageAction=DownloadPackage;ReturnCode=0x80072f78
    Затронутые рабочие нагрузки
        Разработка мобильных приложений на .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.0.26228.0)
    Затронутые компоненты
        Xamarin (Component.Xamarin,version=15.0.26228.0)
        Xamarin Profiler (Component.Xamarin.Profiler,version=15.0.26228.0)
        Xamarin Remoted Simulator (Component.Xamarin.RemotedSimulator,version=15.0.26228.0)
        Xamarin Workbooks (Component.Xamarin.Inspector,version=15.0.26228.0)
    Сведения
        Не удалось скачать WebClient: Время ожидания операции истекло.
        Не удалось скачать Bits: Файл не найден.
        Не удалось скачать WinInet: Function: InternetOpenUrl, HR: -2147012744, Message: Unknown error 12152
```

Comment: Первое, что посоветую - освободить место на диске под установку необходимых компонент, а второе - определиться, что именно вам нужно из *Xamarin* и не ставить все 26Гб, насколько я помню, я доставлял около 6Гб. Вот ссылки: [Настройка и установка Visual Studio и Xamarin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/mt613162.aspx) и вот эта: [Документация по Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/#pivot=workloads&panel=mobile)